# Disable swapping for one slot in Azure Web Apps

Tags: azure, web-applications, deployment, slots

Let's say I have an app in Azure with 2 slots: staging and development. At the moment, I can freely do swaps between production, development and staging.

Is there a way to disable swaps for development? So it's possible to swap prod & staging, but not possible to swap development with anything.

Answer (score 0):

> Disable swapping for one slot in Azure Web Apps

If you want to swapping product and stage slots, you could turn on the auto swapping on the staging slot. If you don't wan to auto swapping with development, we could turn it off in the development slot. I don't know why you want to disable swapping with development. If we swap it manually, we could choose it any slot we want. We could get more detail info about swapping slot from the [azure document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-staged-publishing#swap-deployment-slots).

[image]

Comment: You see, I want development to not shop up in the dropdown for the manual swap slot choice. Can I do that?

Comment: Based on my experience, it is not supported to do that. And based on my understanding, the slot is supposed to do that.